# rally wsapi permissions consistency

Tags: web-services, permissions, rally, consistency

Are Rally permissions consistent or eventually consistent? because many workspace and project permission tests I wrote are failing. They were passing 2 months ago.

What i do is I create a workspace permission and then immediately after the response from the rally server I set a GET for that permission, but I get the old, stale data.

I note again: all my WSAPI permission tests were passing 2 months ago, and I did not change anything in my code, so I'm assuming something changed on the WSAPI end.

--

some extra info: i am using node-rally library and i wrote a thin wrapper library on top of that to edit permissions.

Also, this might be irrelevant, but I get these warnings when creating workspace permissions, which i dont understand why. I need to specify all 3 of these to create the workspace permission!

```
Warnings:
  [ 'Ignored JSON element workspacepermission.Workspace during processing of this req... (length: 85)',
    'Ignored JSON element workspacepermission.User during processing of this request.',
    'Ignored JSON element workspacepermission.Role during processing of this request.' 
  ],
```

EDIT: code I'm using

```
rallyUtil.getWorkspacePermission = function(personRef){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    restApi.query({
        type: 'workspacepermission',
        limit: Infinity, 
        fetch: ['Workspace', 'User', 'Role', 'ObjectID', 'UserName', 'Name'],
        query: queryUtils.where('User', '=', personRef),
        scope: { workspace: workspaceRef }
    }, function(error, result) {
        if(error) deferred.reject(error);
        else deferred.resolve(_.find(result.Results, function(wPermission){ return areSameRefs(wPermission.Workspace._ref, workspaceRef); }));
    });
    return deferred.promise;    
};
rallyUtil.setWorkspacePermission = function(personRef, permission){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    restApi.create({
        type: 'workspacepermission',
        limit: Infinity,
        data: { Workspace: workspaceRef, User:personRef, Role:permission },
        scope: { workspace: workspaceRef },
    }, function(error, result) {
        if(error) deferred.reject(error);
        else deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;    
};
rallyUtil.setWorkspaceAdmin = function(personRef){
    return rallyUtil.setWorkspacePermission(personRef, 'Admin');
};
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your code to see where you're creating the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a little bit by eliminating the duplicate promises.  All of the restApi methods already return promises (implemented using Q) so your setWorkspacePermission can become this:

```
rallyUtil.setWorkspacePermission = function(personRef, permission){
    return restApi.create({
        type: 'workspacepermission',
        data: { Workspace: workspaceRef, User:personRef, Role:permission },
        scope: { workspace: workspaceRef }
    });    
};
```

That being said, I'm not sure what else might be going on.  Does the create return successfully with a created record?  Is it possible that the permission already exists and that's why it's ignoring the new one?

Comment: ah, missed that in the docs. Yes it does return successfully. nothing fails or errors (except i do get those 3 weird warnings). No, if the permission already existed, my tests wouldn't be failing so that would not be the issue. I still think it might be an 'eventual consistency' issue between your database instances. because it only happens when i send the requests consecutively (yes, the first request finishes before the second gets sent), but if i give it a 1 second pause between requests, it passes.

Comment: that's probably what it is.  i would guess this is the case for any newly created object in wsapi, not just permissions.  my guess is something changed a couple months ago with respect to scaling out the backend that caused the behavior you're seeing now.

Comment: I figured out the problem was a commit where you disabled the cookie jar (idk what that is). when i set jar:true in the requests, the permissions requests worked again